# How to apt-get latest package version

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I need to upgrade my version of gnome-control-center from `gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1` to `gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.11` as it should hopefully fix something.

The problem is that I cannot seem to make my system become aware that `1:3.4.2` exists.

if I do, `apt-show-versions -a gnome-control-center` it will not give me any mention of the new version `1:3.4.2`

I guess I need to add the repo to my apt-get sources. But how do I find out what this source is?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gnome-control-center

I know this is a dumb question but its driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work the way you expected. The repositories your Ubuntu distribution has configured contains only binaries for software in version that were compiled, tested, patched, compiled, tested against your version of the distribution.

To get version newer that is available on repositories you have two options:

1. Find PPA that may contain software you're interested in in versions you are looking for. Follow the instruction and add it into your repository list (is it easy in *Synaptic*).
2. Compile to software from sources. That may cause real mess in your packages installed if you do it *not kosher* way. So please read manuals & howtos about preparing your own package.

Comment: Forgive the dumb question but how do I find the PPA details so I can install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gnome-control-center/1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.11

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center shows that Precise Pangolin has this package available.

Enable `updates` channel to receive new version of packages.

Comment: Finally the problem boiled down to my /etc/apt/sources.list not having the `-updates` sources.

cheers